# Fail to execute 'else' statements when 'if' condition is not met

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-3.7

I am trying to print numbers based on 2 user input numbers. If the first is smaller than the second, print from the smaller to larger. If the first is greater than the second, print from the larger down to the smaller.

Both the statements in if & else statements have been tested to contain the correct logic. However, only the if statement works, but when the else condition is tested, system fails to execute the else statements.

```
def question1c():
    firstNum = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    secondNum = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    if firstNum < secondNum: 
        for n in range(firstNum, secondNum + 1):
            print(n)
    else: 
        for n in range(secondNum, firstNum - 1, -1):
            print(n)
question1c()
```

## Scenario 1:

```
Enter first number: 10
Enter second number: 12
10
11
12
```

## Scenario 2:

```
Enter first number: 12
Enter second number: 10
12
11
10
```

## Actual results for Scenario 2:

```
Enter first number: 12
Enter second number: 10 <-- fails to execute else statements
```

Comment: Check that `range(secondNum, firstNum - 1, -1)` does what you think it does.

Comment: Hi @ItamarMushkin, yes the statement does work if i were to put it in the 'if' statement instead.

Comment: As mentioned by @ItamarMushkin, the `else` is definitely executing, but the `for` statement is being skipped due to the arguments you are giving the `range()` function.

Comment: You are trying to count from 10 to 11 by a negative increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is when `firstNum = 12` and `secondNum = 10`, then the `else` is executed alright (because `12 >= 10`), but then your `range` is:

```py
range(10, 11, -1)
```

So the loop doesn't execute at all and nothing is printed (because you're trying to go down from `10` to `11`.

As you can see you would want to change the `range` to:

```py
range(firstNum, secondNum - 1, -1)
```

---

Alternatively, you could eliminate the conditions and use the direction in one `range`:

```py
firstNum = int(input("Enter first number: "))
secondNum = int(input("Enter second number: "))

direction = 1 if firstNum < secondNum else -1

for n in range(firstNum, secondNum + direction, direction):
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

secondNum is smaller than firstNum so you cannot go down.  Switch them.

```
else: 
    for n in range(firstNumNum, secondNum - 1, -1):
        print(n)
```